# MYSQL (large) UPDATE performance is essentially I/O bound: what lessons to learn?

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have this fairly large myISAM table (95M+ rows) to update once a day (5M+ rows).

The query is straightforward

```
UPDATE main_table a JOIN updated_values b ON a.id=b.id set a.theCount=b.theCount;
```

---

**Time to execute**

1. SSD RAID 5 : 960s
2. ramDisk : 124s
3. MEMORY tables : 20.1s

---

These figures show that the UPDATE call is I/O bound (20s to execute when the data is already in memory...). Not clear, however, what to do. RamDisks and MEMORY tables require writing the data to a stable medium. Converting a table from MEMORY to MyISAM takes forever. Such that the fastest solution appears to be to copy the MyISAM files to the ramDisk, update, and copy back to the SSD raid, which takes less than 20s RT.

Is there any way to configure mySQL buffers such that there would be no need to bother with a ramDisk? (this system runs on a Mac)

Comment: Are `a.id` and `b.id` indexed? What does `EXPLAIN [query]` say.. Did you also try profiling the UPDATE query with -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html

Comment: "Such that the fastest solution appears to be to copy the MyISAM files to the ramDisk, update, and copy back to the SSD raid, which takes less than 20s RT." This is asking for trouble... If you can't handle the table locking time (960s) the UPDATE query needs consider switching to InnoDB engine..

Comment: 1. yes, both ids are indexed how else would 5Mx95M complete in 20 seconds??

2. table locking is not a problem in and of itself.

Comment: Does changing join condition to `a.id=b.id and a.theCount<>b.theCount` make any difference?

Comment: You can also try a hybrid approach: put updated_values table into MEMORY table while keeping bigger one on disk.

Comment: Haven't tried a join with additional condition on count. I doubt there'll be a significant change as most if not all counts are different.